# Changing columns names in Pandas with hierarchical columns

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe with a hierarchical index:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((2, 4)))
>>> df
   0  1  2  3
0  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1

[2 rows x 4 columns]
>>> df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b'], ['i', 'ii']])
>>> df
   a      b    
   i  ii  i  ii
0  1   1  1   1
1  1   1  1   1

[2 rows x 4 columns]
```

Is there an easy way to change the column names under 'b'? I thought the following was intuitive, but it does not work.

```
>>> df['b'].columns = ['iii', 'iv']
>>> df
   a      b    
   i  ii  i  ii
0  1   1  1   1
1  1   1  1   1

[2 rows x 4 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Renaming a columar multi-index is a bit akward ATM (and rename it self it doesn't handle the multi-indexes in a nice way). If its an index of the frame, its pretty easy to `reset_index/rename/set_index`.

So 2 choices: (this will get easier in 0.15.0 as well); right now have to set all the levels, even the ones you are not changing.

```
In [39]: df.columns = df.columns.set_levels([['iii','iv'],df.columns.levels[1]])

In [40]: df
Out[40]: 
   iii      iv    
     i  ii   i  ii
0    1   1   1   1
1    1   1   1   1
```

Or easiest simply to recreate and set a new index (for all the columns).

Comment: I was hoping to keep the first level the same, but then alter the second one so it reads `i ii iii iv`.

Comment: hmm, didn't see what you wanted then. best just to create the index you want and assign it directly (e.g. ``pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`` is another creation function)