# python replace string function throws asterix wildcard error

Tags: regex, python-2.7, pandas, wildcard

When i use `*` i receive the error

`raise error, v # invalid expression`
`error: nothing to repeat`

other wildcard characters such as `^` work fine.

the line of code:
`df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('*agriculture', 'agri')`

am using pandas and python

edit:
when I try using `/` to escape, the wildcard does not work as i intend

```
In[44]df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['agriculture', 'dfad agriculture df'])

In[45]df
Out[45]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [agriculture, dfad agriculture df]
Index: []

in[46]df.columns.str.replace('/*agriculture*','agri')
Out[46]: Index([u'agri', u'dfad agri df'], dtype='object')
```

I thought the wildcard should output `Index([u'agri', u'agri'], dtype='object)`

---

edit:
I am currently using hierarchical columns and would like to only replace `agri` for that specific level (level = 2).

original:

```
df.columns[0] = ('grand total', '2005', 'agriculture')
df.columns[1] = ('grand total', '2005', 'other')
```

desired:

```
df.columns[0] = ('grand total', '2005', 'agri')
df.columns[1] = ('grand total', '2005', 'other')
```

I'm looking at this link right now: [Changing columns names in Pandas with hierarchical columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921727/changing-columns-names-in-pandas-with-hierarchical-columns)

and that author says it will get easier at 0.15.0 so I am hoping there are more recent updated solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to the asterisk `*` at the end in order to match the string 0 or more times, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
In [287]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['agriculture'])
df

Out[287]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [agriculture]
Index: []

In [289]:
df.columns.str.replace('agriculture*', 'agri')

Out[289]:
Index(['agri'], dtype='object')
```

**EDIT**

Based on your new and actual requirements, you can use `str.contains` to find matches and then use this to build a dict to map the old against new names and then call `rename`:

```
In [307]:
matching_cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('agriculture')]
df.rename(columns = dict(zip(matching_cols, ['agri'] * len(matching_cols))))

Out[307]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [agri, agri]
Index: []
```

Comment: thanks for the info. so now i do not receive an error, however (as explained in the above edit) the wildcard does not work as i had hoped now

Comment: mm thanks for the edit. that makes a lot of sense, and when i run your example it works. however when i run it with my dataframe and add in `inplace=True`, i am getting a `keyerror`. however, I think that's just on my part. You would suggest using `inplace=True`, yes?

Comment: probably but I don't have your real data and your code but I think the above should work fine

Comment: ahhh ok sorry i was not more specific originally. I think the problem I am encountering is due to the hierarchical columns. I will update above.. I should have specified this earlier. I did not think it would make a differnece

Comment: If you have hierarchical columns then you can't rename an individual values for a given level, you have to pass a list of values for all columns at that level using setlevels